# Function to check if website is an image

Tags: javascript, php, html, image

I have a function to check if url is an image or not.
The problem is that when a user posted a gif image it didn't work. 
It shows an X instead of the image. The website is in html but it gets it as a image/gif.

any ideas?

what user posted: https://media.giphy.com/media/CwbErAWpTQDxS/giphy.gif
it is an html page not a gif.

my function:

```
function isImage($url){
$url_headers=get_headers($url, 1);

if($url_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
   $url_exists = false;
} 
else {
    $url_exists = true;
}

if($url_exists){
    if(isset($url_headers['Content-Type'])){
        $type=strtolower($url_headers['Content-Type']);

        $valid_image_type=array();
        $valid_image_type['image/png']='';
        $valid_image_type['image/jpg']='';
        $valid_image_type['image/jpeg']='';
        $valid_image_type['image/jpe']='';
        $valid_image_type['image/gif']='';

        if(isset($valid_image_type[$type])){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @LawrenceCherone it shows image/gif here

Comment: What is your question exactly? Content-type returned by this url is "text/html".

Comment: the header returned from that url is Content-Type => image/gif

Comment: php curl get header then check what you get?

Comment: it is returning here image/gif my question is how to solve it because when I add image html tag on it, it will not show the image. How can I check it to not add image html tag on that.

Comment: Open the link in your browser and check the response header there. The content type will be text/html.

Comment: @rlanvin in my browser yes, but my function will return image/gif. and I don't know why.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your function. Check the answer from @TimG below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe giphy is sniffing the http header "accept" - or perhaps the user agent string.  In any case, when I used a tool to show headers for that url I see "image/gif", but chrome inspector reveals a web page being delivered with text/html as content type.

giphy has a web page talking about how to embed.  There may be a way around this with ajax, but that's out of scope for your question.  As is, it appears that giphy does not want hotlinking.

[Giphy Article on Embedding Images](https://giphy.com/posts/how-to-embed-giphy-gifs-on-your-website)

Comment: @RickJoe unless you want to hard-code it, and just deny all URL's starting with `media.giphy.com`

Comment: I would inspect the url for the presence of "giphy.com" and adjust accordingly.  either you want to forbid the adding of giphy.com images or you need to adjust the way you display them with special logic elsewhere in your application.

Comment: @TimG I was curious so I did a test with curl. You are right it is indeed the Accept header - as soon as it contains "text/html" giphy will serve the html page instead of the gif.

Comment: @rlanvin, so it might be that one could set up an ajax call to a proxy script on the OP's server that sets the headers appropriately to load the image, base64 encode it, and deliver it back to the browser.  all in all way too heavy handed.  darn those clever giphy engineers!

Comment: @rlanvin thanks for the investigation - I WAS super curious. :)

Comment: if (strpos($url, 'media.giphy.com') == true) { return false; }